# React + Firebase - Deleting firebase object inside mapped components

Tags: reactjs, firebase, lodash

I'm trying to pass the key of my project object through to my mapped components in order to delete them.

UPDATE: using the `_.forEach(project, (proj, key) => <Project key={key} {... more props here}/>)` Throws an error about objects not being valid react children. I'm guessing this is because the `project` i'm forEaching over needs to be turned into an array? I keep trying to format in `componentWillMount()` but when i try to run `forEach` with `setState` and push to a new array i keep getting duplicates

```
componentDidMount() {
    projectRef.on('value', snap => {
      this.setState({projects: snap.val()})
      // somehow i need to create a new array of objects that include the key.
    })
  }
```

UPDATE: i removed the codepen example. I like code sandbox better. Much better. =)

[And here's the code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jqNOJ9gpy) (If you get an error about the [DEFAULT] app already being defined just refresh the output browser and it will work. I don't know why it's doing that... oh well. I added my attempt with `forEach` on the code sandbox example. Hopefully someone can let me know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Each `item` should have a unique identifier in the form of a `key:value` pair in the data structure in firebase. So you should look for that in the `props.item` of each `<Display />` component. It would be useful to see a short and straightforward snippet of how your data is structured in firebase.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, map returns an array of the values of the object, in this case an object you can then access via the props in the `<Display />` component, but not the key of each element of the object.

Perhaps you could use lodash's [forEach](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#forEach) in order to loop and have access to both the key and the value of each element in your data collection. Like that you can pass the key (that will be the target for the remove method) as a specific prop and the value as the item prop in the component.

```
export default class extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      items: null
    }
  }
  render() {
    return() {
      <div>
        {_.forEach(this.state.items, (item, key) => 
           <Display key={key} itemKey={key} item={item}/>
        )}
      </div>
    }
  }
}

// then the display component
removeItem() {
   firebase.database().ref({this.props.itemKey}).remove();
}
render() {
  return (
    <div>{this.props.item.name} <button onClick={this.removeItem}>X</button>
  )
}
```

Here's a simple live example of how `forEach` works:

https://jsbin.com/xolejoj/edit?js,console

---

### Edit 08-12-2017

The problem with your code is that you're missing the fact that `map` is returning the key and the value of each element of the object. In this case your object has a key string and a value that is the object. Then on your JSX you're trying to pass the key as it were a part of the object (value) but is not, therefore you're getting an undefined value in the component's props.

Change your code to this:

```
<div>
  {_.map(projects, (proj, key) => <Project 
      key={key} 
      title={proj.title}
      subtitle={proj.subtitle}
      desc={proj.desc}
      itemKey={key} // just the key of the object
    />
  )}
</div>
```

The thing is that the key of each object is the identifier in firebase and the value is the object with the data you need, but that object doesn't have a `key` property, therefore it was evaluated to null.

Comment: This is exactly what i was after! Let me run this in the morn and then i'll mark your answer as gold once i've confirmed this is indeed the path to glory! Cheers mate. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Ok. So close. I'm getting an error ```Objects are not valid as a React child``` I have a feeling it's due to how i'm setting  state with the snapshot.val() then running forEach over them. I'm just not sure... Ideas?

Comment: That means that in one of your render methods you're passing a javascript object instead of a valid JSX. Could you set up a reduced live sample using codesanbox?: https://codesandbox.io/ All you need is a github account

Comment: I created the codepen example already. I'll update it with my _.forEach attempt though. Codesandbox looks cool though. I'll check it out. I dont' really like codepen.

Comment: Ok i created code sandbox example. Much better than codepen however there is a bug with re loading my firebase init so you have to refresh the output browser to get it to work after you make any changes

Comment: Yep, it seems that codesandbox has some issues when using firebase. You should create or get some data and use it directly in the sample. The problem, as mentioned, is not on the firebase of your code but in a `render`method somewhere. Most likely there is some `{this.props}` around that's returning an object instead of a string and causing React to throw that error.

Comment: i'm working on the code sandbox now. the firebase does work if you refresh the faux output browser.

Comment: I'm trying to construct a new object now by adding each key in the forEach loop but i'm pushing each character in the string and not the whole string... uggh...